# Javascript doesn't update Inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create some temperature converters, but i can't do it because innerHTML doesn't update the values in the Input Boxes.

I used some console.log to check for the values of valID and valNum, but both seemed ok, so i don't understand why the code doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <h2><u>Temperature Converter</u></h2>

    <p>
        <label>Fahrenheit</label>
        <input id="fahrenheit" type="number" placeholder="Fahrenheit" onchange="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)" oninput="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Celsius</label>
        <input id="celsius" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" onchange="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)" oninput="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Kelvin</label>
        <input id="kelvin" type="number" placeholder="Kelvin" onchange="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)" oninput="tempConverter(this.id, this.value)">
    </p>

    <script>
        function tempConverter(valID, valNum)
        {
            valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
            if (valID === "fahrenheit")
            {
                document.getElementById("celsius").innerHTML = (valNum - 32) / 1.8;
                document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML = ((valNum - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15;
            }
            if (valID === "celsius")
            {
                document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = (valNum * 1.8) + 32;
                document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML = valNum + 273.15;
            }
            if (valID === "kelvin")
            {
                document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = ((valNum - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32;
                document.getElementById("celsius").innerHTML = valNum - 273.15;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: An `input` doesn't have an `.innerHTML`, but it does have a `.value`

Comment: Many thanks Tibrogargan. I saw an example online that worked with .innerHTML but mine wasn't. But now everything is alright with ".value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`document.getElementById("mytext").value = "My value";`

Comment: Yes, everything works well now with "value". Many thanks.